# How is dark matter meant to explain the faster than expected rotation of galaxies?

Tags: gravity, forces, dark-matter, galaxies, galaxy-rotation-curve

The stars on the outer edges of galaxies go around faster than they should be. How is dark matter meant to account for this? if you just add more mass wont that just give it a greater gravitational force? So we would still expect the outer stars of galaxies to be going slower than the ones near the center. Whats the flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: It's the distribution of the mass that counts. If you bung a load of extra mass at the centre of the galaxy then it will indeed just increase the overall gravitational force. However the dark matter is spread throught the disk and extends outwards beyond it. This is explained in the question I've suggested as a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does dark matter halo outside a galaxy help to explain galaxy rotation curve?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68955/)

Comment: So there is more dark matter the further away from the center? If this is the case why? why isn't it just randomly distributed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, more mass would mean a greater gravitational pull. A greater gravitational pull, in turn, means that an object would have to be going *faster* at a particular distance if it is moving in a circle.  Similar to an object tied to a string and going in a circle: the faster it's moving, the larger the required force (in this case tension).