# Regarding Dark Energy/optical illusion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity, kinematics

If we assume that the substance of time is slower in the presence of very high gravity( early years of the universe) then is it not reasonable to assume that as matter gets further apart, that time, due to less gravitational effect will speed up creating the illusion that the velocity of matter is accelerating.

Comment: Related to the notion of time dilation on large scales: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161453/25301

Comment: It might be an illusion, but I  wouldn't call it an [optical illusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_illusion), because it is not caused by the visual system.

Answer (score -3):

Oh so you are saying space moved slower in the past because time moved slower and time moved slower because space was more dense? Yea I can see that. Except the formula for velocity takes into account change of time.

Velocity = change of distance / change of time

Velocity = $\frac{\Delta Distance}{\Delta Time}$

Maybe they didnt account for time moving slower when calculating the velocities?

Comment: Like a snapshot now compared to a snapshot then

Comment: http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2017/03/recharged-debate-over-speed-expansion-universe-could-lead-new-physics