# How fast does time pass in a void?

Tags: general-relativity, time-dilation

How much faster does time pass in a comsic void compared to earth?
I know that the passage of time on earth is affected by the gravities of Earth, the Sun and the Galaxy, as well as by nearby galaxies.

Comment: See [Why isn't the center of the galaxy "younger" than the outer parts?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/161453/why-isnt-the-center-of-the-galaxy-younger-than-the-outer-parts) and just feed in the position of the Sun rather than using the centre of the Milky Way.